# Looking for direction to find a specific hardware

Tags: hardware, bluetooth-low-energy, mobile-applications

I am struggling finding a specific hardware, here is what I need :

- Bluetooth Low Energy Beacon
- good range
- Button on it to send a signal to my iOS/Android app
- Possibility to switch off/on (not mandatory)
- LED on it : It should receive signal from the app (to change the color, it - should show different colors of the LED)
- small max size 2cm diameter, 5mm thick
- cheap :)

I am not used to search IoT stuff and find it hard to find my way around, I tried alibaba but too many things, maybe you guys have some website to share.

Answer (score 5):

The [flic](https://flic.io/) button from shortcut labs meets most (but not all) of your requirements. (not cheap and the light only comes on when the button is pushed iirc, but might be hackable/fixable at the firmware level)

I think you might struggle to find something that meets your size requirements given a cr 2032 battery is 2cm diameter before you add any case and is 3.2mm thick leaving only 1.8mm to get a circuit board and button and led into the package.

Comment: There are smaller coin cells, and most of the current generation coin cell gadgets are built with QFN BTLE chips rather than the smaller WLCSP versions.  For an always-on beacon a CR2032 is probably too small, for something that only activates a bit on each button push, energy capacity could probably be lower, but peak current draw will still be pretty high so would be more the limiting factor.